# How to update lambda function's source code hash after its created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-aws-modules

I am using Terraform to create AWS Lambda function and also to store package in the S3 bucket. For brevity I am not including all the code

```
// Create S3 Bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
     bucket = var.s3_bucket
}


 // Create lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_function" "middleware" {
  function_name = var.function_name

  s3_bucket = var.s3_bucket
  s3_key    = var.s3_bucket_key
  source_code_hash = var.source_code_hash  //to trigger updates


  runtime = "nodejs14.x"
  memory_size = 1024
  timeout = 900
  handler = "dist/src/lambda.handler"

  role = var.role

  environment {
    variables = {
      DATABASE_URL = "postgres://****"
    }
  }
}
```

Terraform is used to create Infrastructure which does not change very often so I am planning to separate terraform deployment from the application code deployment. In this case application code is middleware code.

The application code deployment (using CI/CD) will create a package and upload it to S3 bucket that lambda will be using. However every time new package is generated its `source_code_hash` will be different and I believe lambda will require updated hash.

**Question**
1> During the application deployment, I don't want to apply terraform again by passing new source_code_hash. (That could be error prone process by accidently updating infrastructure)
How do I update lambda_function's source code hash after its created as a part if CI/CD?

2>Is this the correct flow I am using by separating Infrastructure deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Typically I see the code and infra in the same place so every code release you just run the Terraform apply with the new hash.  Since you are deploying your Lambda function with Terraform, Lambda **IS** your infrastructure and you should use TF to make code updates. Given this, you must run `terraform apply` so Terraform does not lose the state of your infrastructure.  If for whatever reason you do need to split the two, instead update the function with the AWS CLI as part of your CI/CD and live with the fact that your Terraform state is not fully in sync with your function's code.